# Styling a google map

Tags: android, google-maps, styling

I want to create an android app that uses google maps. I used the [Google Maps APIs Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com) and created the json file. What changes do I have to make in my app's code(android studio) in order to apply changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After map ready, you could apply style changes in OnMapReady

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;
    setMapStyle();
}

private void setMapStyle() {
    MapStyleOptions style = new MapStyleOptions("[" +
            "  {" +
            "    \"featureType\":\"poi.business\"," +
            "    \"elementType\":\"all\"," +
            "    \"stylers\":[" +
            "      {" +
            "        \"visibility\":\"off\"" +
            "      }" +
            "    ]" +
            "  }," +
            "  {" +
            "    \"featureType\":\"transit\"," +
            "    \"elementType\":\"all\"," +
            "    \"stylers\":[" +
            "      {" +
            "        \"visibility\":\"off\"" +
            "      }" +
            "    ]" +
            "  }" +
            "]");

    mMap.setMapStyle(style);
}
```

Check these links : [MapStyleOptions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MapStyleOptions), [GoogleSamples](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/StyledMapDemoActivity.java)

Answer (score 3):

Adding a custom style to google map is very easy. Check the below code.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        try {
            // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
            // in a raw resource file.
            boolean success = mMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            MapsActivity.this, R.raw.style_json));

            if (!success) {
                Log.e("Map", "Style parsing failed.");
            }
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("Map", "Can't find style.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Create a folder name raw under res/ folder. Copy and paste the json from the google maps api styling wizard to a style_json file and add it to the raw folder. Thats it. Style will be applied. Check this [example](https://github.com/suresh-chandran/CustomStyleMap).

Answer (score 3):

create inside **res/** a directory called **raw**. in raw you create a file name.json and put the json from [Google Maps APIs Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) inside it

[image]

in the *onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)* method put that code

```
googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        this, R.raw.name.json));
```

and it is all :)